# Hashing string in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hash

I know there's a function to obtain the hash value from a varchar in Oracle, but when I run the query to see the returned value it sends the following message.

```
ORA-00904: : identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 70, columna: 7
```

What I'm doing is the following:

```
select DBMS_CRYPTO.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Foo'), 3) FROM dual;
```

It should return the SHA-1 of the string.

Comment: Actual answer is here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56658/23369. (The heck is wrong with Oracle?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works for me

```
SQL> select DBMS_CRYPTO.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Foo'), 3) FROM dual;

DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('FOO'),3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
201A6B3053CC1422D2C3670B62616221D2290929
```

Are you sure that the user that is running this has been granted `EXECUTE` access on both the `UTL_RAW` and the `DBMS_CRYPTO` packages?  If line 70 of your code is this `SELECT` statement, I'd wager that column 7 is where the `DBMS_CRYPTO` call starts and that you don't have access to the `DBMS_CRYPTO` package.

Comment: For UTL_RAW I'm sure it has access 'cause if I run `select utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Foo') from dual;` it does return a value. For DBMS_CRYPTO I'm not completely sure, but if I execute `select * from ALL_OBJECTS A WHERE A.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE';` the package appears so I suppose I have access

Comment: @BRabbit27 - if the statement breaks when you add the call to DBMS_CRYPTO it seems a fair bet that it's the call to DBMS_CRYPTO that's causing your 'invalid identifier' error.